# selenium ide testing tool

Tags: selenium-ide

We are using selenium ide tool in our project for testing the web application.
while executing, in the Login page we will give userid and password, 
I need to extract those userid and passwords to an excel file.
I need add some script
can some body help me in this issue.

Radhika

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Extending the IDE using Selenium-RC is your quickest bet. [Here](http://functionaltestautomation.blogspot.com/2009/10/dataprovider-data-driven-testing-with.html) is an excellent tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can make js file containing array for userid and passwords.
In that array you can store value which you want to pass.
Add that file as options > selenium IDE extension.
Now you can able to extract those values in your script.